# Titanium push notifications ios error callback doesn't seem to fire when user denies push notifications

Tags: apple-push-notifications, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Titanium 5.2.2
Appcelerator Studio 4.5.0
iOS 9.0
Device iPhone SE

When the user denies push notifications none of the callbacks are fired. This blocks the user flow unfortunately. Anyone has found a solution to this problem?

```
function registerForPushNotifications(callback){
var deviceToken = null;
// Check if the device is running iOS 8 or later
if (Ti.Platform.name == "iPhone OS" && parseInt(Ti.Platform.version.split(".")[0]) >= 8) {

    // Wait for user settings to be registered before registering for push notifications
    Ti.App.iOS.addEventListener('usernotificationsettings', function registerForPush() {

        // Remove event listener once registered for push notifications
        Ti.App.iOS.removeEventListener('usernotificationsettings', registerForPush); 

        Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
            success: deviceTokenSuccess,
            error: deviceTokenError,
            callback: receivePush
        });
    });

    // Register notification types to use

    Ti.App.iOS.registerUserNotificationSettings({
        types: [
            Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT,
            Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND,
            Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE
        ]
    });

    // Process incoming push notifications
    function receivePush(e) {
        alert('Received push: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
    }

    // Save the device token for subsequent API calls
    function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
        Ti.API.info("Registered for push notifications");
        deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
        callback(deviceToken);
    }

    function deviceTokenError(e) {
        alert('Failed to register for push notifications! ' + e.error);
        callback();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Push callbacks will not be fired if user denies to activate Push.

By **'This blocks the user flow unfortunately'** if you mean that you have written your code to run further only when device is successfully registered for Push, then I would like to suggest you that put the Push code in a separate file or function and keep your remaining app code independent to Push code.

To know whether your device is registered for Push successfully, I suggest you to use variables as you can never rely upon Push code to run your all remaining app code.

If you mean something else, then please share some more info. Thanks